# jQuery Tabs Content Overflow + heightStyle and refresh break tabs

Tags: css, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery-UI Tabs vertically at [my site](http://hr.barton.s483.sureserver.com/tool_new1b.php) and was having no issues until I started loading content in the tab panels and found that the parent tab panel div does not grow with the content, e.g. tab "Static Info".  I can "fix" the issue by setting the parent div class CSS to **overflow: auto**, which then creates a vertical scrollbar on the parent div.  However, I would really prefer if the parent div would just grow with the child content.  I did try a couple of clearfix options, including:

`$( ".tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-helper-clearfix" );`

when intializing the document, but none of the clearfixes made any difference.  As I was seeking solutions, I did try adjusting the heightStyle and tab refresh to see if either of those would make a difference.  What I found was that this did nothing:

`$( ".tabs" ).tabs({ heightStyle: "fill" });`  I also tried "content" and "auto" with also no luck.

However, when I tried the alternative as documented at api.jquery.com/tabs:

```
var heightStyle = $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle" );

$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle", "fill" );
```

the tabs layout completely broke.  The content was all there, but the ul list was at the top of the page with no tabs, followed by all the panel content.  I got the same result with:

`$( ".tabs" ).tabs( refresh );`

I did verify that my jQuery UI in general was working (e.g. I tried

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs({ event: "mouseover" }); which worked fine.
```

This seems like it should be simple, but I've reached a relative dead end with CSS, and I don't understand what is going on with the jQuery- why it breaks with heightStyle and refresh.  Any ideas or advice on getting my content to behave itself are very much appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the following from:

```
#tabs-left > div {
    height: 35em;
}
```

to:

```
#tabs-left > div {
    min-height: 35em;
}
```

Comment: As I was uploading my amended CSS file with your solution, I was chanting, "please work, please work, please work"; so you can imagine how thrilled I was when it did- lol!  Thank you for your kind assistance. Cheers!